# Probability of at least one element for each class in a multinomial distribution

Tags: sample-size, multinomial-distribution, probability-inequalities

Given a multinomial distribution

$$X \sim \mathcal{M}(n, p_1, \ldots , p_K)$$

If I know $p_1 \ldots p_n$ I can easily obtain the following probability by repeatedly sampling from a multinomial distribution

$$P( X_1 \geq 1, \ldots X_K \geq 1) \geq 0.95.$$

But if I do not know their values but I know that $p_i \geq 0.01 $. How can I prove that for

$$ Y ~ \sim \mathcal{M}(n, 0.01, 0.01, \ldots 0.01)$$

it holds

$$P( X_1 \geq 1, \ldots X_K \geq 1) \geq P( Y_1 \geq 1, \ldots Y_{100} \geq 1)$$

I want this result to obtain a lower bound for the first probability. I don't have any doubt this is true but also I do not have any evidence besides some Montecarlo simulations.

Note that $K \leq 100$ due to $p_i \geq 0.01$ and that if $n <K$ both probabilities are 0.

Comment: Well, if n < k, it it can’t hold true.

Comment: True. I need this to find a minimum sample size in the case of unknown frequencies so n will always be big enough.

Comment: Also the inequality holds for n < K since   $K \leq 100$  due to the fact that $p_{i} \geq 0.01$.